# in my django project i get a 'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'concrete_model' error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I have added a form for my django rest project. However, I keep getting a 'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'concrete_model' error.

In my User class I have added a new field 'password' and I was trying to create a form. and call the serializer upon it.

**My Model:**

```
class User(models.Model):
gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, choices=GENDER)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
position = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
birthday = models.DateField(auto_created=False, blank=False)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='something')
```

**Form**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')
```

**Serializer**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = UserForm
    fields = '__all__'
```

Here is the Error that occures:

AttributeError at /users/
'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'concrete_model'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UserSerializer` needs to the refer to your model, not the form:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I am facing a similar problem (though scenario is not the exact one). Could you please help me out on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708484/how-to-resolve-attributeerror-modelformoptions-object-has-no-attribute-concr)?